# Spectral Theorem / Quadratic Form Minimization Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, quadratic-forms

**Here is the problem:**

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix.

Let $S = \{ \mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n : ||\mathbf x|| = 1 \} $ denote the unit sphere.

Let $Q(\mathbf x) = \mathbf x ^TA\mathbf x $ denote the quadratic form associated to $A$.

Show that if $\mathbf x_0 \in S$ is a point where $Q$ achieves its global minimum on $S$, then $\mathbf x_0$ is an eigenvector for $A$. What is the corresponding eigenvalue?

I do not even know where to begin with this problem. This is apparently a Spectral Theorem problem, but I don't see it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you also have that $A$ is Hermitian?

Comment: Well, it doesn't specify anywhere, and I've never dealt with Hermitian matrices, so I can't really say.

Comment: How is $S$ defined, is $S$ whole $\mathbb{R}^n$, or is it a smaller set? possibly convex? Is it the unitball?

Comment: Oh, right. I'll edit the post to fix that. $S$ is defined elsewhere and I forgot to put it in.

Comment: You need to know whether or not $A$ is symmetric, it is *not*, in fact, an eigenvector if $A$ is unsymmetric.

Comment: I am pretty sure you need $A$ to be symmetric otherwise the statement is not true. Counterexample is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\-1&1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: $A$ is definitely symmetric because it satisfies the equation for $Q(\mathbf x)$.

Comment: That statement is not well-posed. $Q(x)$ is perfectly valid whether or not $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: Hmm. Looking at Wikipedia: "Let $Q$ be a quadratic form defined on an $n$-dimensional real vector space. Let $A$ be the matrix of the quadratic form $Q$ in a given basis. This means that $A$ is a symmetric $n×n$ matrix such that
$Q(x)=x^T Ax.$" Does that not necessarily apply here?

Comment: Furthermore, I just noticed that it's stated elsewhere that we can assume that $A$ is, in fact, symmetric. I'll edit the OP accordingly. Sorry about all that!

Comment: There are many matrices $A$ (just add any skew-symmetric matrix), giving you the same $Q(x)$ back. That's why we agree usually to take the symmetric representer, so we can use all the nice properties of symmetric matrices.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough and rigorous response, @DimitarM.H.! May I ask what your mathematical background is?

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help. I am a grad student in Control Theory and I was fortunate to benefit from some really good math classes at my Institute :).

Comment: Wikipedia's article is not as clear as it could be. It is by no means *necessary* that $A$ is symmetric simply by virtual of it being in a function of the form $Q(x)=x^TAx$. After all, if $A$ is *not* symmetric, than $x^TAx=x^T(A+A^T)x/2$. What Wikipedia is saying is that *given* a quadratic form $Q(x)$, *there exists* a symmetric matrix such that $Q(x)=x^TAx$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A$ is symmetric, than the answer follows from spectral theorem indeed. First notice, if $A$ is symmetric we diagonalize the matrix with respect to an orthonormal basis and therefore:
$\min\limits_{||x||=1} x^TAx = \min\limits_{||x||=1} x^TQ^T\Lambda Qx = \min\limits_{||z||=1} z\Lambda z$, where $\Lambda := \text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2, ... ,\lambda_n)$. We used the fact that $Q$ are isometries (unitary matrices), hence $z = Qx$ implies $||z|| = ||Qx||$. 
Now $\min\limits_{||z||=1} z\Lambda z = \min\limits_{\sum_i z^2_i=1} \sum\limits^n_{i=1} \lambda_i z^2_i = \min\limits_{j} \lambda_j=\lambda_{min}$. With $j^*$ being the corresponding index, the minimizing $z$ has the entries $z_{j^*} = 1$ and else $z_{j\neq j^*} = 0$. Using $z = Qx$ to find the corresponding minimizer $x$, we find that $x^*$ is the eigenvector of unit length to that corresponding minimum eigenvalue $\lambda_{min} = \lambda_{j^*}$.

Notice that with the same argument we can see that $\max\limits_{||x||=1} x^TAx =\lambda_{max} $, with the maximizing $x$ being the eigenvector to that maximum eigenvalue.

The required result would not hold, if $A$ is not symmetric. Instead another result would hold: Noticing, that $A$ can be decomposed into a symmetric and skew-symmetric matrix, $A = A_{sym} + A_{skew} = \frac{1}{2}(A^T+A) + \frac{1}{2}(A^T-A^T)$ and that $x^TAx = x^TA_{sym}x$, we can see that $\min\limits_{||x||=1} x^TAx$ or $\max\limits_{||x||=1} x^TAx$ would be the $\lambda_{min}$ and $\lambda_{max}$ of the matrix $A_{sym}$ with minimizer and maximizer being the corresponding eigenvectors of $A_{sym}$. Those eigenvectors and eigenvalues do NOT relate back to $A$ without any further assumption.

Answer (score 4):

Using the Spectral Theorem is circular reasoning, since the proof of the spectral theorem uses this fact!

One way to prove this without invoking the spectral theorem is to use Lagrange Multipliers.

Observe that

$\begin{align*}
Q(x+v) &= \langle x+v, Ax +Av \rangle\\
&=\langle x, Ax \rangle + \langle v, Ax \rangle+\langle x, Av \rangle+\langle v, Av\rangle\\
&=Q(x)+\langle v, 2Ax\rangle+\langle v, Av\rangle
\end{align*}$

where in the last line we have used $\langle v, Ax \rangle = \langle x, Av \rangle$ since $A$ is symmetric.

By the definition of the derivative, we have that $\nabla Q(x) = 2Ax$.

We are trying to minimize $Q$ on the unit sphere $g(x) = 0$, where $g= |x|^2$.  We can compute that $\nabla g(x) = 2x$.

We know the minimum exists since the unit sphere is compact.  Lagrange multipliers tells us that at the minimum we have

$$\nabla f(p) = \lambda \nabla g(p)$$ for some $\lambda$ at the minimum $p$.

But using our computations above this says

$$Ap = \lambda p$$, so $p$ was actually an eigenvector. Moreover $Q(p) = p \cdot \lambda p = \lambda$.

Note that this proves the hardest part of the Spectral theorem:  that there is at least one eigenvector.  To complete the proof, observe that if $v$ is an eigenvector, then $A$ restricts to a linear map from $v^\perp \to v^\perp$, since for all $x \in v^\perp$, $\langle v, Ax \rangle = \langle Av, x \rangle = \lambda \langle v, x \rangle = 0 $, since $x \perp v$.

We can then view $A$ as operating on a vector space ($v^\perp$) of dimension $n-1$, so induction instantly solves the problem.

Comment: Whether or not it is circular to use the spectral theorem, I find is a really subjective matter, since it depends on everyone's individual mathematical education. Depending on how you learned Linear Algebra or Linear Operator Theory, you will have seen one fact preceding the other one. At least in my experience and my perception of standard literature, I find it more common, to not need the presented fact to prove the Spectral Theorem, but just use fundamental notions of normal and self-adjoint operators.

Comment: @DimitarHo  Can you point me to a source which proves Spectral theorem without this fact?

Comment: I would need to research, which book it has been drawn from, we have been using Axler, Naylor & Sell, Lax, Strang. The version I know of, combines in the complex linear space case, the spectral theorem for linear operators on finite-dimensional linear spaces with the notions of normal operators having only simple generalized eigenvectors, and having orthogonal eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: I can recall that in the real linear space setting, we indeed showed that there is at least one eigenvector and then pursued by induction. But proving that there exists one eigenvector, we used facts about linear dependence and polynomials of self-adjoint operators.

Comment: Beautiful proof!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think $A$ is supposed to be symmetric. In that case:

Using the spectral theorem, $A=S^{-1}DS$ where $S$ is orthogonal and D is a diagonal matrix. $D=diag(d_1,\dots, d_n)$

Let $k_1,\dots,k_r \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ such that: $d_{k_1}=\dots=d_{k_r}=\min\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}\{d_i\}=d$

So
$$
Q(\mathbf x) = \mathbf x^TS^TDS\mathbf x= (S\mathbf x)^TD(S\mathbf x)
$$
Let $\mathbf y= S\mathbf x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
\vdots \\
y_n
\end{bmatrix}$

Note that since $S$ is orthogonal, $||\mathbf y||=||\mathbf x||=1$

We also have $A\mathbf x=$

And $Q(\mathbf x)= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n d_iy_i^2\geq d$

$$\begin{align}
Q(\mathbf x)=d & \iff \mathbf y \in \operatorname{span}(\mathbf e_{k_1},\dots,\mathbf e_{k_r}) \\
 & \iff \mathbf y \text{ is an eigenvector of D, with the eigenvalue d} \\
 & \iff D \mathbf y=d\mathbf y \\
 & \iff S^TDS \mathbf x = dS^TS\mathbf x \\
 & \iff A\mathbf x= d\mathbf x
\end{align}$$

Which means that $Q$ attains its minimum on the eigenvectors of its smallest eigenvalue.